# cmake override linking library

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, linkage

Lets say I have a target A
Which has targets (libs) B, C, D as a dependency

Now I have a target T which has as a dependency the target A and of course implicitly B, C and D.

Lest assume I want to replace lib D with some lib X as a stub for my tests. 
How can I achieve that in cmake?

Comment: Why not add an `option(USE_TEST_X, "Use lib X for testing")` and then `if(USE_TEST_X) set(D_LIBRARIES D) else() set(D_LIBRARIES X.a) endif()`. You can set the default value of it to be false.

Comment: because it is a part o my unit-tests and this test is compiled together with the rest of the targets. I don't want to compile specific targets for just testing.